# Finding root of 3d surface in R

Tags: r, 3d, contour

I have a function , foo(x,y), that creates a 3d surface from x,y coordinates. I need to find all values of (x,y) where foo=0. Currently, I am calculating foo at every point on an (x,y) search grid, but this is computationally expensive. Is there a way to give R foo, and have it return all values of (x,y) where foo=0?

Comment: For a great many functions of two variables, there are infinitely many such points so you couldn't possibly find them all. In any event, if you want help -- why not provide `foo()`?

Comment: Any approach will be computationally expensive. Do you have reasonable bounds? Is 0 a minimum or a maximum? You could use `optim` (which looks for a minimum) with a bunch of varied start values, which would let you do a search of a much coarser grid, finding the "closest" 0 to each start point.

Comment: Using `uniroot()` applied to the function `function(x) foo(x,y)` (when `y` is fixed) or `function(y) foo(x,y)` (when (`x` is fixed)) might help. Evaluate `?uniroot` for details.

Answer (score 0):

With `contourLines`:

```
foo <- function(x,y) x^2 + y^2 - 1
x <- y <- seq(-2, 2, len=200)
z <- outer(x, y, foo)
cr <- contourLines(x, y, z, levels=0)
```

---

```
> x <- cr[[1]]$x
> y <- cr[[1]]$y
> foo(x[10], y[10])
[1] -4.438003e-05
```